# Chainlink Large Responses

Tags: ethereum, solidity, ipfs, chainlink

I run this code from the [chainlink documentation](https://docs.chain.link/docs/large-responses/) but didn't get the image.

```
function requestBytes() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
    address oracle = "0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8";
    bytes32 specId = "7a97ff8493ec406d90621b2531f9251a";
    uint256 payment = 100000000000000000;
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(specId, address(this), this.fulfillBytes.selector);
    req.add("get","https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmZgsvrA1o1C8BGCrx6mHTqR1Ui1XqbCrtbMVrRLHtuPVD?filename=big-api-response.json");
    req.add("path", "image");
    return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, req, payment);
}

event RequestFulfilled(
    bytes32 indexed requestId,
    bytes indexed data
);

function fulfillBytes(
    bytes32 requestId,
    bytes memory bytesData
)
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(requestId)
{
    emit RequestFulfilled(requestId, bytesData);
    data = bytesData;
    url = string(data);
}
```

Comment: I just tried running this example from the docs on Kovan, and it worked fine. Can you try again? Steps I took were compile the project in remix, deploy on kovan, fund with some LINK, execute the request_bytes function, wait 30 secs, then execute the data and image_url getter functions to see the results https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&evmVersion=null&runs=200&version=soljson-v0.8.6+commit.11564f7e.js&url=https://github.com/smartcontractkit/documentation/blob/main/_includes/samples/APIRequests/GenericBigWord.sol

Comment: where do you get kovan testnet ??

Comment: I deployed the example contract code to the Kovan public testnet using MetaMask. Where were you deploying it to?

Comment: I tried to deploy rinkeby test network as I don't have the Kovan public testnet.

Comment: @yamnaiftikhar Can you share the contract address on the Rinkeby testnet as well as the transaction invoking the `requestBytes()` function?

Comment: @PetrHejda here is an example using the same code: https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x1d1fd1385f4eecb9e05ef4bded4282c46f3301716081eb24b3f99349f654102a

Comment: Thank you @Roch. My reason behind asking OP for their tx details is searching for the issue in the actual transaction - such as incorrect `data`, insufficient LINK balance, possibly using a call instead of a tx (if there's no tx hash), ...

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for troubleshooting job execution issues is to check your oracle contract for any recent transactions within the related block explorer:

- If there are no transactions within your oracle contract during the associated timeframe, this likely means the job run errored out within the Chainlink node. Check your Chainlink node logs (or navigate to the respective job run from within the Chainlink GUI) for more information.
- If there is a recent transaction within your oracle contract during the associated timeframe, but the transaction failed with an `out of gas` exception, you'll need to increase the gas limit of the respective oracle job, as the gas required to write the data that you are requesting exceeds your node's configured limit (typically 500000 gas). You can configure this limit on a per-job basis by adding the `gasLimit` attribute to your `ethTx` job task: https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/oracle-jobs/all-tasks#eth-tx-task.
- If there is a recent transaction within your oracle contract during the associated timeframe, but the transaction failed due to some other `execution error`, you may have some logical error in your consumer contract's fulfill function. Check your contract's fulfill function for coding errors, and try again.

I hope that helps!